# Reloading CSS For :hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a hover game that makes flashing squares, then makes the squares turn white once hovered on, but the flashing squares' color overrides the hover. I use chrome, and here is the code. Can you please tell me a method that refreshes the CSS? The scale would be larger.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .a{
        display:inline;
        background-color: blue;
        color: blue;
        width: 100px;
        float: left;
      }
      .b{

        display:inline;
        background-color: red;
        color: red;
        width: 100px;
        float: left;
      }

      h1:hover{
        background-color: white;
        color: white;
      }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div" class="div">
    </div>
    <script>
      for(var i = 1;i<12;i){
        var a = document.createElement('h1')
        document.getElementById('div').appendChild(a)
        a.innerHTML=("HI")
        a.id="id"
        document.getElementById("id").setAttribute('class', 'a');
        a.id=null
        i=i+1


        var b = document.createElement('h1')
        document.getElementById('div').appendChild(b)
        b.innerHTML=("BYE")
        b.id="id"
        document.getElementById("id").setAttribute('class', 'b');
        b.id=null
        i=i+1
        }




        for(i=1;i<10000;i){
          setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].setAttribute("style","background-color:red;color:red")
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('a'),
                             item => item.setAttribute("style","color: blue;background-color:blue"));
          },(2*i-0)*1000)
          setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].setAttribute("style","background-color:blue;color:blue")
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('a'),
                             item => item.setAttribute("style","color: red;background-color:red"));
          },(2*i-1)*1000)
          setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementsByClassName('b')[0].setAttribute("style","background-color:blue;color:blue")
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('b'),
                             item => item.setAttribute("style","color: blue;background-color:blue"));
          },(2*i-1)*1000)
          setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementsByClassName('b')[0].setAttribute("style","background-color:red;color:red")
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('b'),
                             item => item.setAttribute("style","color: red;background-color:red"));
          },(2*i-0)*1000)
          i=i+1
        }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

What the code does is it creates the arsenal of HIs and BYEs. Then it changes the color of the things using its class name, and then it fails because it doesn't refresh the CSS.

Comment: Change classes instead of inline style then set up hover rules for those classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "!important" to css style you want to override

```
h1:hover{
    background-color: white!important;
    color: white!important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`tag` styles have lower priority than `.class` or `#id`. Just add `!important` for hover or create h1 with some class that won't change, and write styles for it.